# Waiting for incoming connection with ide key 'xxxxx'

Tags: magento2.4.1, phpstorm, xdebug

In phpstrom variable getting "Waiting for incoming connection with ide key 18836" while trying to run debug magento2 using xdebug. Xdebug is installed correctly in my Ubuntu system,checked with php -v. I thought, issue with phpstrom xdebug configuration. how to configure xdebug(3.0.3) in phpstrom (2020.3.2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please follow these steps: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/configuring-xdebug.html#integrationWithProduct from the official documentation.

Also, as far as I know Xdebug’s default debugging port has changed from 9000 to 9003 in xdebug3, so please consider that as well.